# xamarin forms customtabbar not showing when navigate

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

my customtabber.cs working properly but how can i navigate another page outside tabbar buttons.

App.Current.MainPage = new NavigatePage(new ContentPage()); is working but when i run this code then customtabbar not showing..

thanks

Comment: each tab can contain it's own `NavigationPage` which is then used to navigate within each tab

Comment: thank you.. but  i have 4 tabpages..  for example 1. contentpage include a button. when click the button i want show 5.conttent page..  not first 4 contentpage. yes i can 5.page but custombar not showing.can you show me example codes. im working with mvvm..  all codes working with viewmodels.

Comment: Instead of adding additional information in comments, please *edit your question* with those details. Its much easier to read carefully formatted information in a question. To get further help, I recommend adding more code to the question. Describing your situation is useful, but also show **exact code and xaml** that is involved. A single line of code such as you have now is not enough, for anyone to understand what you are trying to do.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

The tabbedpage's tabbar will not show when you used `App.Current.MainPage = new NavigatePage(new ContentPage())`. It only displays on the tabbedpage's child page or when you navigate from the child page which is wrapped in `NavigationPage`.

**So you can try Jason's solution, make each tab contain it's own NavigationPage:**

In the TabbedPage.cs:

```
public TabbedPage1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Children.Add(new NavigationPage(new Child1()){Title = "Child1",IconImageSource = "icon1.png"});
    Children.Add(new NavigationPage(new Child2()){Title = "Child2",IconImageSource = "icon2.png"});
    ...
}
```

And navigate from the child1 to a new contentpage with the button clicked event:

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Navigation.PushAsync(new ContentPage());
        }
```

And then the tabbar will still show in the new contentpage and it will also have a back button in the navigation bar. You can put the `NavigationPage.HasBackButton="False"` in the new ContentPage's xaml file to hide the back button.

Answer (score 0):

not working.. because no prop Navigation.
im using viewmodel.
and only fixed
Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new companyDetailsPage(cmp.Id), true);

but when do this then my tabbar not visible..

Comment: Did you test this in the code behind instead of the viewmodel? It worked in my project without viewmodel. In addition, you can try to use the `(Application.Current.MainPage as TabbedPage).CurrentPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new companyDetailsPage(cmp.Id));` in the viewmodel.

Comment: yes..this is working without viewmodel.. but i need inside viewmodel.

Comment: So you can try the `(Application.Current.MainPage as TabbedPage).CurrentPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new companyDetailsPage(cmp.Id));` in the viewmodel.